# Google Sheets api append method is not adding a line after the last row

Tags: google-sheets, append, google-sheets-api

It is supposed that [values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append) method should add a line when it meets an empty row starting from the first row of the defined range. If there is no gaps between existing rows, then it should add a line in the end of the defined range table.

In my case I use the following values to append a row after for example 22-nd row (using python), when all rows till 30 are full:

```
range="MySheet!A22",
valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",
insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
body={"majorDimension": "ROWS", "values": [['asd', 'asd2']]}
```

But I got it inserted after the headings (9-th row) with the style of the heading. And in response:

```
"tableRange": "MySheet!A1:C9"
"updatedRange": "MySheet!A10:B10"
```

[image]

`MySheet!A13` or `MySheet!A14` or `MySheet!A14:C14` didn't work also to enter a row after 13/14-th rows.

This behavior is out of the used programming language/environment, as I get the same result using their web interface test `Try it!`.

**-- UPDATE --**

Here is a [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w7v0N8NPuQB7lE1fG0tOcCoiGg2-l4VjFODOe3mdWcM). Better if you make a copy and run your tests on it.

And here is the [test data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append?apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221w7v0N8NPuQB7lE1fG0tOcCoiGg2-l4VjFODOe3mdWcM%22%2C%22range%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22includeValuesInResponse%22%3Afalse%2C%22insertDataOption%22%3A%22INSERT_ROWS%22%2C%22valueInputOption%22%3A%22USER_ENTERED%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22majorDimension%22%3A%22ROWS%22%2C%22values%22%3A%5B%5B%22qwe2%22%2C%22rty2%22%5D%5D%7D%7D&apix=true) that I want to append. You can use the same form only replacing `spreadsheetId` with your copy one. You can see that the range is set to `test` which means that it has to search all the tables inside the sheet, find the last one, and add the data after it. But data is added on the 10-th row.

It behaves as expected (adds line at the end) if I:

1. Delete dummy image or remove its cell (**A2:C4**)
2. Delete `some text` or remove its cell (**I2:I6**)
3. Delete one of the columns from **C** to **G**
4. Remove link on the URL in cells **B10** and **B11** (if I remove only **B10** link, data is added in between of two rows)[image]

**Please support the opened issue by staring it: [Issue Tracker Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/185272184)**

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between your issues in your question and your sample image and your scripts. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Hello Serob_b, I am not sure I understand either. Can you share a copy of the sheet that you are testing this with? As you mention a lot of ranges but they are not visible in your screenshot. Have you read the [guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#appending_values) on this subject?

Comment: @Tanaike Please have a look on update.

Comment: @iansedano Updated

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. From your updated question, I remembered that I have experienced the same issue with your situation. So I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Serob_b and @Tanaike - very strange behavior. Do you have an idea of how to reproduce this? I can reproduce the problem on the sample sheet provided by Serob_b, but I cannot find a way to reproduce it on a brand new spreadsheet. Do you know how?

Comment: @iansedano As a sample situation, for example, when 2 sample values of "a1" and "b2" are put in the cell "A1" and "B2", respectively, and `[["sample"]]` is appended with the sheet name (`Sheet1`) using the method of "spreadsheets.values.append", the value is put to the cell "B3" which is the 1st empty row and the last column. When the sheet name and range is used for this (`Sheet1!A:A`), the value is put to the cell "B2". I'm not sure whether this is the specification and bug.

Comment: @iansedano On the other hand, when AppendCellsRequest of the batchUpdate method is used for above situation, the value is put to the cell "A3". If this explanation was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike, do you know if this is caused by the hyperlink only?

Comment: @Tanaike I have opened a ticket to Google. Can you upvote(star) it so it has more chances to be reviewed?  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185272184

Answer (score 3):

#### Issue and workaround:

When the method of "spreadsheets.values.append" is used, I have experienced the same situation with you. In that case, I thought that it might be the current specification at Google side or a bug. So, as a workaround, I have changed the method from "spreadsheets.values.append" to "spreadsheets.batchUpdate". In my environment, when AppendCellsRequest of the method of "spreadsheets.batchUpdate" was used, I confirmed that the issue could be resolved.

When this workaround is reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample curl command:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SpreadsheetId]:batchUpdate' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"requests":[{"appendCells":{"sheetId":[sheetId],"rows":[{"values":[{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"sample1"}},{"userEnteredValue":{"stringValue":"sample2"}}]}],"fields":"userEnteredValue"}}]}' \
  --compressed
```

- When you want to test this using "Try tis API", you can also use [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%22your%20spreadsheet%20ID%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22appendCells%22%3A%7B%22sheetId%22%3A0%2C%22rows%22%3A%5B%7B%22values%22%3A%5B%7B%22userEnteredValue%22%3A%7B%22stringValue%22%3A%22sample1%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22userEnteredValue%22%3A%7B%22stringValue%22%3A%22sample2%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22fields%22%3A%22userEnteredValue%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D).

#### Result:

When I used above request for your sample Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained. You can see the values are appended to the sheet of "test".

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AppendCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest)

## Added:

From your following replying,

> I don't know anything about `Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as the wrapper API`. I'll look on it. Can you provide some docs?

You can see the sample situations at https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#samplesituations But, I think that if you want to use this method for your situation, it is required to create the script for achieving your goal. So as the additional information, for your situation, I would like to introduce the method using Web Apps as the wrapper API.

### Usage:

#### 1. Create sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet which is your sample Spreadsheet.

```
function doPost(e) {
  const sheetName = "test";  // This is the sheet name in your sample Spreadsheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const values = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.");
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps.

The detail information can be seen at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app).

1. On the script editor, at the top right of the script editor, please click "click Deploy" -> "New deployment".
2. Please click "Select type" -> "Web App".
3. Please input the information about the Web App in the fields under "Deployment configuration".
4. Please select **"Me"** for **"Execute as"**.

   - This is the important of this workaround.
5. Please select **"Anyone"** for **"Who has access"**.

   - In this case, the user is not required to use the access token. So please use this as a test case.
   - Of course, you can access to the Web Apps using the access token. In that case, please set to `Anyone with Google account` or `Only myself`. When you want to use the access token, please include the scopes for Drive API like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.
6. Please click "Deploy" button.
7. Copy the URL of Web App. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
   - You can see the detail of this at the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### 3. Testing.

As the test of above Web Apps, you can test this using a curl command. In that case, please replace the URL with your URL. At above flow, the access token is not required to be used. So when the following curl command is run, the values of `sample1` and `sample2` are put to the columns "A" and "B" at the 1st empty row of `test` sheet.

```
$ curl -L -d '[["sample1", "sample2"]]' "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"
```

- When this curl command is run, when your setting is correct, `Done.` is returned.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#samplesituations)

Comment: I'll try it, but actually I am entering around 50 cells and it would be hard to set each cells type and so on.. Do you know any other easier way of entering cells without this kind of details?

Comment: @Serob_b Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your question, I couldn't notice about `I'll try it, but actually I am entering around 50 cells and it would be hard to set each cells type and so on.`. I deeply apologize for this. In that case, for example, how about using the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as the wrapper API? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: You don't have to apologize for anything, your suggestions can really help. I don't know anything about `Web Apps created by Google Apps Script as the wrapper API`. I'll look on it. Can you provide some docs?

Comment: Is this your repo? 
https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script

Comment: @Serob_b Thank you for replying. About the samples using Web Apps as the wrapper, you can see the sample situations at https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#samplesituations But, I think that if you want to use this method, it is required to create the script for achieving your goal. So I added the sample flow for using this method in my answer. Could you please confirm it?